# Offset of symbol 'Symbol' inconsistent

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, pc-lint

Can someone explain me PC-Lint error no. 38 with an example...

```
38    Offset of symbol 'Symbol' inconsistent (Location)  -- A
      member of a class or struct appears in a different
      position (offset from the start of the structure) than an
      earlier declaration.  This could be caused by array
      dimensions changing from one module to another.
```

I keep getting errors like...

```
Offset of symbol 'ClassX::access1' inconsistent (conflicts with line 92, file U:\ABC\ABCApp.h, module U:\ABC\ABCApp.cpp)
```

where `access1` is a member variable of type enum `ACCESS` declared in `ClassX`. And that enum `ACCESS` is defined in a different header file `access.h`.
`access.h` is included in `stdafx.h`.

```
typedef enum
{
    ACCESS_NONE      = 0,
    ACCESS_READ      = 1
} ACCESS;
```

Not sure what is problem here. Where is the inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the definition of `ACCESS` that is the problem, but the position of `access1` member in class `ClassX`. You either have double declaration of the class or (most likely) some rogue `#pragma pack` that is in effect when compiling one .cpp, but is not in effect when compiling another.